# Subtraction and addition variables in bash script

Tags: bash, variables

I have some script with name `name.sh`, in script I have lines

```
days_shutdown_notification=$1-1
days_shutdown=$1
days_notification_deleting=$1+4
days_delete=$1+5
```

I want to use my script with some numbers, for example `name.sh 10`. But I got error.
I tried to use this code `days_shutdown_notification=$1(($days_shutdown_notification-1))`  but also did not work.

How I can use variables for Subtraction and addition?

My script:
[pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/2fPaDSbt)

Comment: `$(( $1 - 1 ))`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Very quick solution! Thank you very much! ^__^

Comment: BTW, if your shell is `bash` and not `sh` you can also have a command like `(( --days_shutdown_notification ))`